# Include git commit information inside a project

Tags: php, git, build

I am working on `php` project. Is it possible to integrate git into the project to have the info from last commit in the `footer`?

I am not using build framework

Comment: Depends on your build process.

Comment: Create a git post commit hook: add a script that will generate a static info file after every git push, then include/parse or do whatever you want  with that file on your backend.

Comment: For this question, I think pre-commit would be better than post-commit.  I think the question means he wants some kind of 'last updated' information in the website footer, based on the last code modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually after searching what I found something like that without using builds

```
echo exec('git log -1 --format=%cd --date=local');
```

That will display the time and date of last commit

Comment: This will trigger git action on *every* page request, which will make your backend much slower. I do not recommend this.

Comment: You probably don't want to be executing this *every* time you display your footer.  It will affect performance.

Comment: I would upvote @AndrejsCainikovs git post commit hook answer if there was one detailing how to do that.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs, yeah but it's just for specified page and for development and testing not production

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski Done. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use so called *git hook* to achieve this. Hooks are literally scripts that execute automatically on specific git actions. The one that you might be interested in is called *git post commit hook*, which is a script that is automatically executed after every commit. Here's how to add one:

1. Create a script `.git/hooks/post-commit`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   git log -1 --format=%cd --date=local > version.txt
   ```
2. Make it executable:

   ```
    chmod +x .git/hooks/post-commit
   ```

That's it. Now after every commit your `version.txt` will be updated with info from your last commit.

Comment: I like this, but if he wants it in his website's footer, isn't post-commit too late?  Unless this is a hook on the server, and version.txt is more like an unversioned data file?

Comment: I would go even further and would generate a `php` file by this script, that would contain some defines, which then can be easily included directly into your `php` project. This will make sure that the text file is not accessed on every page request.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski Why it would be *too late*? Please elaborate... This file would be literally recreated after every `git commit` command.

Comment: I was thinking if the generated version.txt also needs to be under version control, then that would require another `git add` and `git commit` - which would basically cause a loop.

Comment: I think the OP's workflow is `git push` on the development machine and `git pull` on the web server...

Comment: Correct. You are right. If server side needs to have this file, you need to add one more hook duplicate, which will be triggered on every git pull.

Comment: Another option would be adding *pre commit hook*, which could commit `version.txt` file automatically once it's changed. But this approach has a cons - you will miss commit SHA, if you need one, but will work if only date & time is required.

Comment: It's actually not working because th idea i want it to be committed to the test server 
What i have done i made the exec like my answer and i cached once in the config file

Comment: You haven't read the comments. Exec commands are not cacheable, only static php part.

Comment: @g33k your test servers could have a post-merge git hook to update version.txt, but version.txt will need to be a data file rather than a source file (e.g. outside of the repo or included in the .gitignore file)

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski, actually i have  done that and tried to test but not changes happened after post-comment  hook 

so I used my answer solution and instead of calling with every page load so I have done in the config once and cached it into the system

Comment: Again, `exec`, obviously, is not cacheable.

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple options for doing that, but I think the best one would be to do it in during your build.

If you're using something like Jenkins, Bamboo or any other CI/CD system, you can create a task to retrieve the git commit, and save it in a readable location by the application. This could be:

- Set it as part of your configuration file
- Set it as an environment variable that you can read
- Save it in a file and read it for each request
- ...

Really, the options are endless, but it depends on the way you're building your project, and how it's being deployed. As you can see, you're not lacking options!

If you don't use a build system, maybe you should be using one then!

Still, you have the option to get the latest commit by executing something like:

```
echo exec('git rev-parse --short HEAD');
```

Which will give you the short commit hash. I'd really recommend using one of the alternative options though.

Comment: I don't build the project just code form scratch pushed and pulled

Comment: @g33k added an edit to the answer, to address your specific case

Comment: thanks I like your answer but I have found the right command for it and I have put it in answer